# Transition for content changing position after slider with various heights

Tags: jquery, css, resize, transition

I've got a slider with slides of various heights. As a side-effect, the content after the slider div will "jump" up and down with each slide change.
Here's my question: How I can I achieve the content after the slider to move smoothly into position when the slider changes height? I played around with the CSS transition property, but to no avail.

To illustrate what I'm aiming at, here's a link to one of Apple's pages who've done it just right: http://www.apple.com/tvos/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, you have this layout:

```
<slider></slider>
<rest-of-content></rest-of-content>
```

Although, in effect, the position of `<rest-of-content>` changes in the page when `<slider>` height is changed, there is ***nothing*** you can change at `<rest-of-content>` to make it jump smoothly. You need to make the `height` property of `<slider>` change smoothly and, automatically, everything else following it in `DOM` will also change position smoothly.

Animating the `height` property of your slider varies greatly depending on the slider you are using, but a good number of them provide the ability to animate changes in height smoothly out of the box and can be done through initialization settings. I'm not endorsing it in any way, but I know for sure [`slick carousel`](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/) has this option. Scroll down to the "Adaptive height" section.

Of course, you might want to keep the slider you use now, and use its callback of initiating a slide change, get the new slide's height and animate the slider container's height to match the new one. In order for your content not to jump, you might want to use a container for the entire slider with `overflow:hidden` and change that container's `max-height` each time the slide changes.

Hope the above makes sense and helps you.

Comment: Andrei, thank you.
That actually helped me a lot and makes perfectly sense.

I'm using Bootstrap Carousel (the specific situation required it) and already found a few threads here that seem to address this issue.

Thus, I consider this one resolved.

Comment: @Pelikhan You are welcome (on StackOverflow). Happy to help and glad you worked it out. :: }<(((*> ::)